# kooboo search for all pages, views and html blocks and labels

Tags: kooboo

Is there a way for KOOBOO search function works for, all internal site? 
I mean search for contents of pages, views, html blocks and labels...

As I can understand, native search function works for only articles

Thank you, for your answer

Comment: If you are using Kooboo, can you add your support please to the Area 51 proposal for a dedicated Kooboo Stack Exchange sub site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79383/kooboo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using a pretty recent version of Kooboo, V4.4.0 or similar. If you are, there are a number of search options available under the menu option: > Content > Search

Under there you can select which "content folders" are added to the search index. Given that Kooboo is a "Content Management System" this is the logical place to expect most of your data / content to be and how to control the way it is indexed.

I'm guessing that you already know about this options though, and this is where you are indexing your "articles"?

I don't believe that indexing of 'Views' and 'Labels' is supported.  They are both too abstract concepts, they are components that are use to build other things.  Trying to index them as separate items goes against the aim of the system.

One final area that my provide you an answer though is to look at the settings for an individual page.  On the 'Settings' tab there is a tick box to tell the system to include the page content in the search index.  This setting should allow "HTML blocks" to be included in the search index and may provide what you are looking for.